# Making UITextField component with limited access

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to make a small SDK for Adding a credit card form. Idea is to make SDK so application can use TextField component from SDK but with limited access. For example, an application can enter text, change UI but I want to disable direct access to read text. I want to expose only the last 4 digits. The application shouldn't access secure data like all 16 digits of the card. I'm not sure how I can disable reading text property from UITextField in this case

EDIT:

Thanks Vadim and Bill for your answers

Here is the code that I wrote based on your suggestions:

```
public protocol CreditCardInputProtocol {
    var lastFourDigits: String? { get }
    var binNumber: String? { get }
    var isCardValid: Bool { get }
}

class CreditCardTextField: UIView {
    
    private var textField = UITextField()
    
    public var textFieldBackgroudColor: UIColor = .clear
    
    public var bottomLineHeight: Float = 1
    public var bottomLineColor: UIColor = .gray
    
    public lazy var bottomLine: UIView = {
        let bottomView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.height, width: textField.frame.width, height: CGFloat(bottomLineHeight)))
        bottomView.backgroundColor = bottomLineColor
        
        return bottomView
    }()
    
    public lazy var font: UIFont = {
        guard let fontTmp = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 14) else {
            return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        }
        return fontTmp
    }()
    
    public var isCardValid: Bool {
        if textField.text?.count == 16 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    
    public var binNumber: String? {
        guard let text = textField.text,
              text.count >= 6 else {
            return nil
        }
        return "\(text.prefix(6))"
    }
    
    public var lastFourDigits: String? {
        guard let text = textField.text,
              text.count == 16 else {
            return nil
        }
        return "\(text.suffix(4))"
    }
    
    public func configurateView(_ frame: CGRect) -> UIView {
        textField = UITextField(frame: frame)
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        textField.borderStyle = .none
        textField.backgroundColor = textFieldBackgroudColor
        textField.font = font
        textField.addSubview(bottomLine)
        
        return textField
    }
    
}

extension CreditCardTextField: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        if string.isBackSpaceCharacter {
            return true
        }else if textField.text?.count == 16 || !string.isNumber {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}

extension String {
    var isBackSpaceCharacter: Bool {
        if let char = self.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")
            if (isBackSpace == -92) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    var isNumber: Bool {
        let aSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789").inverted
        let compSepByCharInSet = self.components(separatedBy: aSet)
        let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joined(separator: "")
        return self == numberFiltered
    }
}
```

This is how it is called right now

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CreditCardInputProtocol {

var lastFourDigits: String?
var binNumber: String?
var isCardValid: Bool = false

var cardField = CreditCardTextField()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    cardField.bottomLineHeight = 0.5
    
    let tf = cardField.configurateView(CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 150, height: 35))
    view.addSubview(tf)
    
}
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to improve it?
This part needs to be customized a lot. The application needs to have ability to change a lot of the UI stuff here. This class will also need to support card number, expiration date, and CVV. So there will be 3 types of text fields there with 3 different validation...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can absolutely restrict reading `UITextField.text` property. Even if you don't directly expose `UITextField` object, if somebody wants to get the text they can at least recursively scan your view hierarchy and find desired textfield.

But if your goal is just to restrict **direct** access to the text, you may just create a custom view with encapsulated textField.

```
/// expose the data you'd like to SDK users
public protocol CreditCardInput {
   var theLastFourDigits: String? { get }
}

///
open final class CreditCardTextField: UIView, CreditCardInput {

   // It's private and not accessible directly for SDK users
   private let textField = UITextField()

   var theLastFourDigits: String? {
      // TODO: get the last 4 digits from `textField`, if there are any
   }
}
```

SDK users will create a `CreditCardTextField` instance and will gain direct access only to the stuff you explicitly exposed in it.

Comment: Thanks Vadim for the suggestion. I have updated the post with the code and some questions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Vadim Popov's comments are correct. In swift and iOS generally, there's no way to remove functionality from a class (e.g. remove readable property .text from the UITextField class). You can override the value returned with something like

override var text: String? {
get {
return "text hidden"
}
}

But your issue is that you can't do even something like that for just one text field. You have to change the class definition, which changes every UITextField in the app.

So what you want, I think, is to take one of two paths:

1. As Vadim said, you can create a UI component that has a managed text field as a subview, and have apps use your component where they would normally use a UITextView. The problem of course is that your component is a UIView, with a subview (the UITextField) which makes it accessible to being found via .subviews property inherited from UIView.
2. Write your own control from primitives. This means drawing the box yourself using graphics drawing primitives, drawing text using text drawing primitives, manage the text value yourself with an internal property, add keyboard event responders to accept input from user, etc. Complicated.

Basically, your problem is that you're trying to use a component (UITextView) that you don't control and remove some of the functionality that the author (Apple) put into the class definition. Swift doesn't allow you to do that without impacting every instance of that class.